# what kind of information we can get if the auto-correlation for an image is a ring or two rings?

Tags: image-processing, autocorrelation

I did the auto-correlation for an image by Mathematica.

The auto-correlation function shows rings as follow..I am sorry that I can not attach the original image here.

From the following auto-correlation one, what kind of information can we get or guess for the original image??

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "information"? It makes sense that the centre is the brightest point since maximal correlation occurs when the image is exactly aligned with itself.

Comment: YES..The midst point is the brightest(biggest). The "information" I want to get is something like Why the correlation function becomes rings? What determines the diameter of the ring?